# Verify if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f(a+h)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Verify if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f(a+h)$

Here's how I approached the problem:

Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = f(a)$

Similarly, $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f(a+h)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(a)+\lim_{h
\rightarrow 0} f(h) = f(a)$

$\therefore \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(a+h) = \lim_
{h\rightarrow 0}f(a) = f(a)$

Comment: Thank you Mr. Ayman for editing the question

Comment: Function $f$ is not necessarily continuous at $a.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit.

- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ is shorthand for: for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
  $$|x-a| < \delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$$
- $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h) = L$ is shorthand for: for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
  $$|h| < \delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad |f(a+h) - L| < \varepsilon$$

Substitute $x = a+h$ into the first expression and compare it to the second.

---

**Comments on your solution:** It's not true in general that $f(a+h)=f(a)+f(h)$, or that $\lim_{h \to 0} f(h)=0$. (In fact, it's almost never true: pick a function $f$ at random and you'll probably find this to be the case).

Comment: that's right @Clive Newstead take for for example $f(x) = cosx $ I really appreciate your review and correction